# Zlib in android only decompressed part of the zlib-comppresed file

Tags: android, compression

The zlib-comppresed file is a text file, it's size is 31KB. After decompress, only part of it are decompressed. Here is my code,

```
public static String decompress(String filePath){

    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        InflaterInputStream inFlaterStream = new InflaterInputStream(is);
        jsonString = Common.convertStreamToString(inFlaterStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    if (jsonString != null && jsonString.length() == 0){
        return null;
    }
    return jsonString;
}

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The line sb.append(line) was just executed once, I guess there might be some Java IO operation problems in above code. But I can't figure it out by myself, anyone can help?